# Enabling MVC client side validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I have

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

in my config and

```
    Html.EnableClientValidation(true);
    Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript(true);
```

in my view and

```
    <script src="~/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

are in the HTML source (as is jQuery) (no JS errors in the browser)

I have one form element with `[Required]` and the form element seems to be rendering OK with the associated `data-` attributes

```
<div class='form-group'>
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Username">en-gb(Username)</label>
                <div class='col-md-10'>
                    <div class='input-group'>
                        <div class='input-group-addon'><span class='fa fa-user'></span></div>
                        <input class="input-validation-error form-control" id="Username" name="Username" type="text" value="" />
                    </div>
                    <span class="field-validation-error help-block" data-valmsg-for="Username" data-valmsg-replace="true">en-gb(The en-gb(Username) field is required.)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

But no client side validation is occurring; the form is always submitted to the server.

What am I missing? What should I be checking?

**Edit**
`TextBoxFor` is in `System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputHelpers` and calls `TextBoxHelper` which in turn calls `InputHelper` in the same file. This calls 
`htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(name, metadata)` which looks like this:

```
public IDictionary<string, object> GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(string name, ModelMetadata metadata)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> results = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        // The ordering of these 3 checks (and the early exits) is for performance reasons.
        if (!ViewContext.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled)
        {
            return results;
        }

        FormContext formContext = ViewContext.GetFormContextForClientValidation();
        if (formContext == null)
        {
            return results;
        }

        string fullName = ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
        if (formContext.RenderedField(fullName))
        {
            return results;
        }

        formContext.RenderedField(fullName, true);

        IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> clientRules = ClientValidationRuleFactory(name, metadata);
        UnobtrusiveValidationAttributesGenerator.GetValidationAttributes(clientRules, results);

        return results;
    }
```

(Source: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/5cb74eb3b2f3#src/System.Web.Mvc/HtmlHelper.cs)

The problem I have is that `formContext.RenderedField(fullName)` returns true and therefore no validation attributes are added to my `input` element.

Comment: There are no `data-val-*` attributes necessary for client side validation in the html you have shown! How are you generating this html? And is it inside a `<form>` element?

Comment: It's just `@TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)` and `@ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username)`

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `data-val-required` attribute?

Comment: Having just set up a new MVC project (that has client side validation turned on by default), it looks like my `input` element is not getting the validation attributes set.

Here's the HTML from the template project.
`<input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-email="The Email field is not a valid e-mail address." data-val-required="The Email field is required." id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Comment: Then all I can suggest is that its either not in a form, or you have also generated another input (perhaps a hidden input) for that property before your `@TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)`

Answer (score 0):

In your views, are you rendering the following code?

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Assuming you're using the default project template, you'll need to include that within the view that you're rendering to enable client side validation... Alternatively, add `Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` to the bottom of your layout file to enable it across all your views.

Also do ensure that `bundles/jqueryval` is defined in the Bundles configuration file.

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to 
<pre>
<script src="~/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
</pre>

Answer (score 0):

`formContext.RenderedField(fullName)` was a red herring, I really don't know what all that was about.

The problem is that I've subclassed the `ValidationAttribute` classes in order to provide globalisation with lookup from a database rather than from resx. This means that they do not appear in the `ModelMetadata`.

One solution is to implement the interface `System.Web.Mvc.IClientValidatable` on the overridden attributes. However, the base classes do not implement this interface, so they must be configuring client side validation by some other mechanism -- and it's this other mechanism that isn't smart enough to pick up subclasses of the out-of-the-box `ValidationAttribute`s.